# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in NextJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

this file contains a Next.js 13 POST route handler that's supposed to publish a post on LinkedIn via their API.

The code also works. When run it and check on LinkedIn I can see a new post. However I still get an error.

When I run it I get this weird error:

```
error TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'res' -> object with constructor 'IncomingMessage'
    --- property 'req' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at serializeJavascriptValueToJSONString (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1074:27)
    at Response.json (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6603:55)
    at NextResponse.json (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:67:35)
    at ApiResponse.sendSuccess (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./utils/successHandler.ts:9:99)
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/linked-in-posts/api/media-posts/publish/[id]/route.ts:100:75)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:254:37)
```

*route.ts:*

```ts
import fs from "fs";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from "@/utils/db";
import axios from "axios";
import { getFileUrl } from "@/utils/storage";
import { ApiResponse } from "@/utils/successHandler";
import { PostStatus } from "@prisma/client";

export const POST = async (
  req: NextRequest,
  { params }: { params: { id: number } }
) => {
  const access_token = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("access_token");

  if (!access_token)
    return ApiResponse.sendError({
      message: "No access token provided",
      name: "NoAccessToken",
    });

  const linkedinPost = await prisma.linkedInPost.findUniqueOrThrow({
    where: { id: Number(params.id) },
    include: {
      post: {
        include: {
          image: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  if (linkedinPost.postStatus == PostStatus.PUBLISHED)
    return ApiResponse.sendError({
      message: "Post is already published on LinkedIn.",
      name: "AlreadyPosted",
    });

  const getMyURN = await axios.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    },
  });
  const userURN = getMyURN.data.id;

  const response = await axios.post(
    `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images?action=initializeUpload`,
    {
      initializeUploadRequest: {
        owner: `urn:li:person:${userURN}`,
      },
    },
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        "LinkedIn-Version": "202306",
        "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
      },
    }
  );

  const upload = response.data;
  const uploadUrl: string = upload.value.uploadUrl;

  const r2Url = getFileUrl({
    filename: linkedinPost?.post.image?.filename as string,
    directory: linkedinPost?.post.image?.directory as string,
  });

  const filepath = `${Date.now()}-${
    linkedinPost.post.image?.filename.split(".")[1]
  }`;

  await downloadImage(r2Url, filepath);

  await uploadImageToUploadURLResponse(uploadUrl, filepath, access_token);

    const publishPostResponse = await axios.post(
      "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts",
      {
        author: `urn:li:person:${userURN}`, // `urn:li:organization:${userURN}` for company page
        commentary: linkedinPost?.post.body,
        visibility: "PUBLIC",
        distribution: {
          feedDistribution: "MAIN_FEED",
          targetEntities: [],
          thirdPartyDistributionChannels: [],
        },
        content: {
          media: {
            title: "title of the video",
            id: `${upload.value.image}`,
          },
        },
        lifecycleState: "PUBLISHED",
        isReshareDisabledByAuthor: false,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
          "LinkedIn-Version": "202306",
          "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
        },
      }
    );
  // the response above posts the post on LinkedIn. I even checked it.

  const urn = response.headers["x-restli-id"]; // This would be the ID of the post. I need it but get the error instead
  const realId = urn.replace("urn:li:share:", "");

  console.log(publishPostResponse);
  // update post in db
  const updatedPost = await prisma.linkedInPost.update({
    where: { id: Number(params.id) },
    data: {
      postStatus: PostStatus.PUBLISHED,
    },
  });

  fs.unlinkSync(filepath);

  console.log(publishPostResponse);
  return ApiResponse.sendSuccess(
    { updatedPost },
    { message: publishPostResponse.statusText }
  );
};

async function downloadImage(url: string, filepath: string) {
  const response = await axios({
    url,
    method: "GET",
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
  });

  fs.writeFileSync(filepath, response.data);

  return filepath;
}

const uploadImageToUploadURLResponse = async (
  uploadUrl: string, // linkedinimage url
  filepath: string,
  access_token: string
) => {
  await axios.post(
    uploadUrl,
    fs.createReadStream(filepath), // Use fs.createReadStream to upload the file
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream", // Set the content type to binary data
      },
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: I'd say the issue is probably within `ApiResponse.sendSuccess()` but you haven't included that in your question